# How can i make an error message popout when the value in my table is 0?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am making a registration form but i want to show an error message when people register after the availseats is 0. Any idea how to do it?

**EDIT:** The code works fine, but users can still register even if the seats are 0. I need a way to not allow them to

Here is my code

```
<?php

require_once("db.php");

$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$course = $_REQUEST["course"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$phone = $_REQUEST["phone"];
$date = $_REQUEST["date"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO registertb(name, course, email, phone, date) VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $course . "','" . $email . "','" . $phone . "','" . $date . "')";


if(mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql))
    {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM coursetb WHERE coursename ='" . $course ."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_row($result);  
            $sql = "UPDATE coursetb SET availseats ='". ($data[5] -1) ."' WHERE coursename ='" . $course ."' AND availseats >= 0";
            mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql);
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Information stored! Redirecting to homepage');
        window.location.href='index.html';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('An error occured while inserting your data. Redirecting to registration page..');
    window.location.href='register.html';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Would it not be prudent to not insert anything if there are no seats?

Comment: Yes it would be great. But i'd also like to have a popup alert saying that.

Comment: I don't see where you are comparing the value of the query, I guess is $data you need to check

Comment: could you give me an example code for a check function?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check the number of available seats before you do the UPDATE, shouldn't you? You are going to end up with a negative number of seats.

Beyond that, when you do your window.location.href line, pass a status (success or failure) as a parameter.

Comment: I've tested this code and it doesn't go to a negative even after a user registers. Thing is i have no idea how to check. (I'm a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether or not there is still a seat left, so do this before you even think of updating anything. Get the course the user wants to register to, and see how many seats there are left.

Assuming your current code is correct, the number of seats seems to be the 6th attribute of the course's table (i.e. you access it by `data[5]`). So just use this information to check if there is still a seat left and handle accordingly.

```
require_once("db.php");

$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$course = $_REQUEST["course"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$phone = $_REQUEST["phone"];
$date = $_REQUEST["date"];

$new_registration = "INSERT INTO registertb(name, course, email, phone, date) VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $course . "','" . $email . "','" . $phone . "','" . $date . "')";

$course = "SELECT * FROM coursetb WHERE coursename ='" . $course ."'";

   if(($result = $mysqli_query($dbconn, $course)))
   {
       $data = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
       if($data[5] > 0)
       {
            $sql = "UPDATE coursetb SET availseats ='". ($data[5] -1) ."' WHERE coursename ='" . $course ."' AND availseats >= 0";
            mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql);
            mysqli_query($dbconn,$new_registration);
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('Information stored! Redirecting to homepage');
            window.location.href='index.html';
            </script>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('All seats are taken! Redirecting to homepage');
            window.location.href='index.html';
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('An error occured while inserting your data. Redirecting to registration page..');
    window.location.href='register.html';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Note that this is not thread safe (I think), when a lot of users access your page at the same time, the check for the amount of seats will run for all of them, and if at that point a seat is left, they will all be allowed through the next `if(data[5])` clause, because none of them have registered yet (and thus the code does not recognize that only one of them is allowed to register). If you care about this you should look into locking your database connection for each request.

Comment: there's an error with this line

   if(($result = $mysqli_query($dbconn, $course)))

Comment: Ok so fix it, maybe it's something with a '(' or ')', I don't have your code so I can't test this myself. Probably just do the `$result = $mysqli_query($dbconn, $course)` before the if and only check like this `if($result)`. That should work. If you want this to work you need to do at least some debugging man, how do you expect to learn this?

Answer (score 0):

Well there's lots of ways to do it. The way you're doing it is very 'vulnerable' because anybody could add anything they like to your script! Save the $_REQUEST['date'] was

```
");DROP TABLE coursetb;"
```

Bye coursetb table! We want to avoid this from happening. Second is you want to do some validation before you add the user.

I can't remember inline methods since using codeigniter, here's a slightly OOP way

```
$db=new mysqli('localhost','root','password','yourdatabase');
function is_not_unique($table,$column,$val){
    $result=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?');
    $result->bind_params('sss',$table,$column,$val);
    $result->execute();
    $db->close();
    return($result->num_rows>=1)?true:false;
}
$errors=false;
if($_POST){
    //this is where a user has submitted the form
    if(is_not_unique('coursetb','coursename',$_POST['course'])$errors=true;
}
if(!$errors){
    $insert=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO registertb (name,course,email,phone,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
    $insert->bind_param('ssssss',$_POST['name'],$_POST['course'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['phone'],$_POST['date']);
    $result=$insert->execute();
    $db->close();
}
$_SESSION['failed_register']=$errors;
```

Probably not 100% as I haven't used mysqli in a LONG time now. But you get the idea.

Then on your registration page do this

```
<?if($_SESSION['failed_register']==true):?>
    <h2>Oh no!</h2>
    <p>We found some errors with your sign up</p>
<?endif;?>
```

You could display these errors anyway you'd like but this is just the basics :)

I can also see in your query you will not return any seats if the row count for seats is 0. So if there is no result there will be no query to check from! Also I'm pretty sure instead of using $data[5] you need to use an array_key string of the column name? Could be entirely wrong.

You could do this:

```
function count_available_seats($table,$course){
    $result=$db->prepare('SELECT availseats FROM coursetbl WHERE coursetbl=?');
    $result->bind_param('s',$_POST['course']);
    $result->execute();
    //need a fetch here
    $seatCount=$result->fetch_array();
    return($seatCount['availseats']>=1)?true:false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check to see if the seats are greater than 0 zero before executing code
- If not, alert user.

see adjusted code below:

```
<?php

require_once("db.php");

$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$course = $_REQUEST["course"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$phone = $_REQUEST["phone"];
$date = $_REQUEST["date"];


$seats_avail_sql="select availseats from coursetb";
$result=mysqli_query($dbconn,$seats_avail_sql);
$seats_avail=0;
if($result){
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $seats_avail=$row["availseats"]; //grab seats avaialble
        }
    }
}




$sql = "INSERT INTO registertb(name, course, email, phone, date) VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $course . "','" . $email . "','" . $phone . "','" . $date . "')";
if(mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql)&&($seats_avail>0)) //only execute code if we have more than 0 seats
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM coursetb WHERE coursename ='" . $course ."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $sql = "UPDATE coursetb SET availseats ='". ($data[5] -1) ."' WHERE coursename ='" . $course ."' AND availseats >= 0";
    mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Information stored! Redirecting to homepage');
        window.location.href='index.html';
    </script>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('No Seats available. Redirecting to registration page..');
        window.location.href='register.html';
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```